# screen.height & screen.width not returning correct values

Tags: javascript, css

I am enabling an overlay upon clicking on button, then when user minimizes the screen overlay is not covering full page. User able to click on buttons when minimizes the screen.

I am setting the `screen.height` & `screen.width` to overlay div. But upon minimizes to certain level again buttons are visible.
`id1` is a `id` of overlay division

```
document.getElementById("id1").style.height=screen.height;
document.getElementById("id1").style.width=screen.width;
```

i want overlay to display over complete web page

Comment: why don't you use `CSS` ?

Comment: This could be done simply with CSS, could you expand on the problem so we can see what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @ths how can we do it in CSS ?

Comment: use `vw` and `vh` units. If you want, I can give you an answer with `CSS` (but you'll have to add `CSS` tag to your question so the answer can relate with the question).

Comment: _“I am setting the screen.height & screen.width to overlay div”_ - why would you do that? There is no guarantee my browser window fills the whole screen in the first place, it might be much smaller than that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Here is what we do to create Overlays..
You should have a parent div like

```
<div class="body_wrapper">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="page_content">
      <-- You Page Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Here inside `<body>` tag you got a `body_wrapper` and inside that you got `overlay` and `page__content`. Now in your style sheet:

```
.body_wrapper {
   position: relative;
}
.overlay {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: But the OP didn't use the `CSS` tag ? He's currently waiting for a `JavaScript` solution.

Comment: He said it in a comment:
@ths how can we do it in CSS ? – HS447 11 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

> The `screen.height` doesn't always return the valid screen height,
>   check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/height#Notes) for more information.

Your task can be achieved by `CSS` and a little bit of `JavaScript`.

The `CSS` has two units that are likely the keys to your issue : the `vw` and the `vh` units. Check this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units#Length_and_size) for more information.

So, here's a demo that shows how you can achieve your task by the help of `CSS` and some `JavaScript` for the event handling.

```js
let trigger = document.getElementById('trigger'),
  triggersClose = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger-close'),
  fullScreen = document.getElementById('fullscreen');

/** click event listener for the button to show the overlay **/
trigger.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fullScreen.classList.add('visible'); /** add .visible class so the overlay is shown **/
});

/** cycle through the buttons that can hide the overlay and add a click event for them **/
triggersClose.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fullScreen.classList.remove('visible'); /** remove .visible class so the overlay becomes hidden **/
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.overlay {
  display: none; /** the overlay is initially hidden **/
  position: fixed; /** stays on the same place even when scrolling in the background **/
  width: 100vw; /** vw : viewport width = 1% of the viewport's width. It changes accordingly when zooming (responsive) **/
  height: 100vh; /** vh : viewport height = 1% of the viewport's height. It changes accordingly when zooming (responsive) **/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: center; /** center the content horizontally **/
  align-items: center; /** center the content vertically **/
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(24, 24, 24, .6);
  z-index: 999; /** stays on top **/
}

.overlay.visible {
  /** this class is used by JavaScript to show the overlay **/
  display: flex; /** flex makes our life easier ! **/
}

.overlay .overlay-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 65%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto; /** adds scrollbars when the content is too much **/
  background-color: #fff;
}

.overlay .overlay-wrapper .overlay-header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #1548a6;
}

.overlay .overlay-wrapper .overlay-header>.text,
.overlay .overlay-wrapper .overlay-body {
  padding: 15px 5px;
}

.overlay .overlay-wrapper .overlay-header>.trigger-close {
  position: absolute;
  width: 45px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #dc3545;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px
}

.overlay .overlay-wrapper .overlay-footer>.trigger-close {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #007bff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<button id="trigger">click me !</button>

<div id="fullscreen" class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay-wrapper">
    <div class="overlay-header">
      <h3 class="text">Message heading</h3>
      <button class="trigger-close">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In facere fugiat aperiam officiis debitis voluptas soluta assumenda cumque reiciendis blanditiis nostrum, consequuntur vero corporis doloribus! Expedita voluptatem illum maiores culpa.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae ex temporibus, possimus commodi, obcaecati nostrum maiores cupiditate voluptas voluptate unde qui quasi accusantium earum dolores pariatur fuga. Optio, officia praesentium.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-footer"><button class="trigger-close">close</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Learn more about [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) (`display: flex`).

Hope I pushed you further.